# Using @helper ShowTree()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<CommentModel> comments) {
    foreach (CommentModel c in comments)
    {
        // ...
```

I don't get how this works. Where does `comments` come from? Exactly what is this looping over?

I want to recursively display a `List<CommentModel>` from the model passed into the view. Each item in that list has its own list of `CommentModel`s, and so on. Is this the right method to use to render those lists, and how do I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your view you can pass comment as parameter :

```
@model IEnumerable<CommentModel>
@ShowTree(Model)

@helper ShowTree(IEnumerable<CommentModel> comments)
{
 //your code...
}
```

simply your action method can be something like this :

```
public ActionResult Comments()
{
            var query = _commentsService.GetAll();
            return View("comments",query);
}
```

Comment: I see, I was just missing the `@ShowTree(Model)` at the top. Thanks!